# Turn off MS Access confirmation of each row deletion

Tags: ms-access, delete-row

I have to prune a large table in MS Access.  Every time I delete a row, Access asks me if I really do want to delete it.  This is driving me nuts.  I can't find a preference about this in Options.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Check this out https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_win10-mso_2016/the-confirm-action-queries-document-deletions-and/03527c32-bdc7-4300-bd54-939046b34f7d

Comment: I got a comfortable position with my right hand on the mouse to click on the first row to remove, left pinkie on the right-hand shift key, and left middle finger on the delete key.  That won't work on my laptop keyboard, though....

Comment: I'd create a delete query and run it from currentdb.execute , then you won't get any messages.

Answer (score 0):

before executing delete query put the below statement. This command makes system messages off

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

after executing the query set to true again.

Comment: Thanks,but -- the annoyance occurs when deleting one row by hitting the delete key, not in the context of a query -- sorry if I wasn't clear.